# gedit weird encoding of standard text file

Tags: encoding, gedit, non-latin

This question is also posted [in AskUbuntu here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061394/gedit-weird-encoding-of-standard-text-file).

I have a standard text file that is shown perfect with cat:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
v0[shape = Mrecord, label = ""]
```

When I use xxd to examine the exact line ending I get this:

```
$ xxd myfile.txt
00000000: 7630 5b73 6861 7065 203d 204d 7265 636f  v0[shape = Mreco
00000010: 7264 2c20 6c61 6265 6c20 3d20 2222 5d0a  rd, label = ""].
```

However when I try to open it with gedit, I get a weird encoding of some non Latin language.
What goes wrong in gedit?

**EDIT**:

Here is the complete source code for reproducing:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ofstream myfile("myfile.txt");
    myfile << "v0[shape = Mrecord, label = \"\"]\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my compilation line:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

In addition, I'm attaching the image file of the the gedit screen:

[image: gedit prnt scrn with non latin letters]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, but it seems that gedit is interpreting the file with the wrong encoding in your case. I don't see an option in gedit to tell it how to interpret the file encoding, which is maybe a reason to switch to a more sophisticated editor for coding. Anyway, I doubt this is a programming question, since it's all about using a GUI application.

Comment: @lenz When doing _Save as..._ in gedit you can select the file encoding.

Comment: @PerlDuck Ok. But that's not the same action as the "Reopen with encoding..." found in other editors.